Color histogram transfer with ffmpeg
I don't know if this is even possible, and I'm new to this, but I'll try and ask anyway:
I have two videos that are largely the same; they are recordings of the same thing. However, in one of them, the colors are wrong. What I want is to in some way transfer or carry over the information about the colors, the brightness, saturation, etc. from the good version to the poor version. Is this at all possible and if it is, how would I achieve this with ffmpeg or some other similar open source software?
